# Problem in starting blackberry Maps in Simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-maps

i am creating simple application for showing Blackberry map in Blackberry.

i was **unable** to open **BB Map** through my app. 
so that i try to open inbuilt Map App that is showing following image

[image: BB Error]

i check my **MSD** setting and my **internet is working** perfect and i can browse from BB Browser

i am using 9530-Verizon-4.7.0.75

what could be problem??? How can i start BB Map in my Simulator??

Comment: I always just assumed that this was an unfortunate limitation of the simulator.  Here's to hoping someone out there knows better!

Comment: I've found that the maps can be temperamental at times. Are you making sure the MDS simulator is completely started before launching the simulator? I've found that on some of the simulators this causes problems if you launch them too early

Comment: @jprofitt yes i have properly checked my MDS and browsing is proper so there is no network issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with rendering issue in simulator. I've been through this when developing a map based app. Map would not render and would show green field.

This is the official response I got from RIM when contacted with the issue:

> Simulator - Blackberry Maps Green Background Issue
>
> Resolution:   Advised customer that BlackBerry Maps functionality has
>   been inconsistent on device simulators. The best method of conducting
>   this testing would be to test on a physical device.

After trying all possible solutions, I gave up. Note that the issue doesn't occur on all systems. If you have access to any other system, try on it. May be you get lucky.

Comment: ohhh is it???
it is really bad if i can't do with my system..
there is no other solution???

Comment: Couple of suggestions: 1) If you have BB device and willing to put up with pain of testing even a small change on device, you can take this route. 2) Have you checked BB Maps in other simulators> You may find some bright spot. 3) Uninstall and reinstall IDE (which ever you are using, Eclipse plug-in or BB JDE) and see if it fixes problem. Even simulators.

Comment: I have tried in 5 different Simulator but it result same

i was facing problem in jde 6.0 so installed 4.6 which runs my app perfect

so changing jde will increase my problem

Comment: why change in JDE will increase your problem if your works for 4.6?

Comment: Project is depended on some lib which are created in 4.6
so if i am crating project in 6.0 then it is creating problem

Comment: i read some BB forums where they show problem is with different JDE versions so as suggested need to try with different versions.

Answer (score 1):

On the simulator phone go into the wifi settings and select a network to connect to. After that you should be able to use the web browser and map applications without problem.